# Special characters in graphics filenames

Tags: graphics, characters, gif

This is my third question in the series of transforming some (~167) documents from HTML to LaTeX.  The other questions were related to [{inputenc}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147565/36281) and [{wrapfig}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147577/36281).

The original document have several graphics (~168) from different sources and different naming conventions.  I am using the `graphicx` package with the `\includegraphics` command. I don't have any problems with PNG and JPEG files with only letters, numbers and hyphens in their names.

I have a couple of GIF files (non-animated) which I attempted to solve using the receipt here: [Convert gif image to png on the fly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/convert-gif-image-to-png-on-the-fly) . Unsuccessfully.  (Also command `\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule` fails in XeLaTeX, and as there are only two files I might rather convert them manually or with my conversion script.)

However I have a problem with PNG and JPEG files with special charactes, mainly those including a period `.` (`includegraphics` things that `something.svg.png` is an unrecognized `.svg.png`), an underscore `_` (if I don't mask that character it attempts to shift to mathmode; if I mask it it does not find the file), and a percent sign `%` (as most of these files were downloaded from internet URL, special chars are masked using the percent sign and I preserved that convention in the filenames.  Again, with the masked percent '\%' '\includegraphics' does not find the file and without it the TeX engine assumes it is an end-of-line and the code breaks).

While I can still rename the files to something LaTeX and `graphicx` will handle, I still would like to now what are the correct way to mask special characters, and particularly `.`, `_`, and `%`.

Comment: You can use `\includegraphics[ext=.png]{filename.with.dots}` (not tested, but it should work theoritically).

Comment: also `_` should not cause any problem in the file name, only if you are typesetting a string with that in. you can use `\@percentchar` for `%` (as long as @ is a letter)

Comment: I think you need the `grffile` package for filenames with multiple dots.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot have more faith, the original graphicx should work fine;-)

Comment: @DonutE.Knot - It's not working. I get the error message `Unknown graphics extension: .dots`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the `\@percentchar` works.  I also declared a macro without @ si I didn't have to put \makeatletter \makeatother each time, however: Isn't there a macro already without @?

Comment: `\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}`

Comment: I just ran into this same problem. I cannot seem to compile with a file name using an `_` when the graphics file is in the directory of the source file but if I use a `.sty` file, it works fine. Weird

Comment: Coming from a Google search, I expected the meaning of "special characters" to be more general than dot, underscore or percent sign. What about accentuated characters from different languages?

Comment: Alright, I found my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290645/95423. `\detokenize{faïlenèime}`