# \input a file whose name contains accented letters

Tags: input-encodings

When I use LaTeX in a Windows system I can easily use the `\input` command with a file whose name contains accented letters, but in a Linux system I get the message

> ! LaTeX Error: File `Préambule.tex' not
>   found.

How to fix that?

Comment: expunge special characters from file names, LaTeX doesn't like them. really, it'll make your life easier

Comment: You might try `\input{\detokenize{Préambule}}`, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried on a Ubuntu system, first by creating a file named `Préambule.tex` and making a test file containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{\detokenize{Préambule.tex}}
\end{document}
```

I compiled with `pdflatex` and this is the terminal output

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file test.aux.
(./Préambule.tex) (./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

So the file has correctly been found and input. However, it's usually better avoiding accented characters (and spaces) in file names.

Comment: thank you very much it works fine with the  \detokenize command (wich iI did not know). So using \input in a windows system is different because there is no need to add \detokenize

Comment: @BoukhouldaHafid That's much operating system dependent; also the input encoding used for the file has a role; this is why it's best avoiding non ASCII characters in file names.