# MikTeX crashes while using characters with umlaut in filename

Tags: miktex, unicode, compilation-error

I am generating PDF files using MikTeX in another script program.
It works perfectly fine except when I compile filenames with characters with umlaut like ä, ü etc.

Here TeXworks crashes completely, does not open the .tex file in the editor.
The log shows the below error message:

```
FATAL texworks - std exception: UTF-8 conversion failed; func=miktex_utf8__open.
```

I have tried adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` without any effect.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Update: I am using a Windows server machine with Windows 10 Pro OS.

Filename: Über.tex
The code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\makeindex
\usepackage[
left=2cm,
right=2cm,
top=1cm,
bottom=1.5cm, % Abstand zum unteren Seitenrand vergrößern 
includeheadfoot
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Seite \thepage \hspace{1pt} von \pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
\setlength{\topsep}{0em}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0em}
%
\begin{table}[h]
%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.55\linewidth}rp{0.2\linewidth}}
%tabbl 1:1
<Ort>
\scriptsize {
UID0001,
\space
UID0002,
\space
UID0003
\space
UID0004,
\space
UID0005 
\space
UID0006

}   

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The compilation is done as follows:

`pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error <path to tex file> -output-directory <storage path>`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which operating system you employ. Please also edit your posting to provide a [minimally compilable example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that generates the problem you wish to fix.

Comment: *I am generating PDF files using MikTeX in another script program.* What does that even mean? How? What program? Using what code?

Comment: Why don't you rename the files, like Ueber.tex? After all, Tex and Latex origin from non-umlaut countries ...

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290645/140133) may help. But, you should totally avoid any special character in naming files, check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12176/140133).

Comment: Just in case, confirm that your input file is saved in utf8 format.